# Independence of random projection and orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices

Suppose we have three fixed unit vectors $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and an (arbitrary) distribution over random matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times d}$: let $P_M = M^T(MM^T)^{-1}M$ and $P^{\perp}_M = I - P_M$ be the projection and orthogonal projection onto the span of $M$, respectively. I would like to formally show that the random variable $A = \frac{x^\top P^\perp_M v}{v^\top P^\perp_M v}$ is independent from the random variable $B = x^\top P_M w$ (i.e., $E_M[AB] = E_M[A]E_M[B]$).

I have verified this in simulation for the class of random matrix distributions that I care about, but (a) I am not sure if this holds in general (b) if it does (or doesn't), I'm not sure how to prove it (or find a counterexample).